# What is the return type of enum |?

Tags: c, syntax

```
enum FileOpenFlags
{
    FileOpenFlags_Create = 1,
    FileOpenFlags_Truncate = 2,
};


FileOpenFlags flags = FileOpenFlags_Create | FileOpenFlags_Truncate;
```

Is it true the return type of `enum |` is also `enum`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the above expression will have the type `int`. However, since `enum`s convert to and from `int` without problems, it's then implicitly converted back to `enum` for the store.

See also [this comp.lang.c FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/struct/enumvsdefine.html).

Answer (score 2):

no it doesn't and c doesn't really care. You can still assign it to an enum even if the value returned by enum | enum is doesn't match the value of any enum you have defined.

They are all ints as far as c is concerned

Answer (score 1):

An enum value is just an integer and operations on enum values are not guaranteed to return a defined enum value.

Answer (score 1):

I usually define flags using #define,

```
#define FLAG_1 0x1
#define FLAG_2 0x2
#define FLAG_3 0x4
```

...

If you use enums and want seperate flags that can be OR'ed together, you would have to assign them a value using the '=' operator.

Comment: And the `enum` way is marginally better because it gives you a C token for the constant instead of a preprocessor define.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should not really be storing the union of those two back into an enum type - since the new value is not a valid value for that enum!  Store them into an int, instead.

Alternatively, take a look at the [c bit field types (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields)

```
struct FOF {
  int Create : 1;
  int Truncate : 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is valid, `(int)3` should be returned in your example.

As far as I'm concerned, C treats enum values as type `int` via an internal cast or something along these lines. The thing with enums is that in C++ they can't be the LVALUE of an operation (because they're not treated as numbers), so you can't increment them or assign them a value. OTOH, you can always use them as the RVALUE (both in C and C++), so:

```
int flags = FileOpenFlags_Create | FileOpenFlags_Truncate;
```

is valid in both C and C++, while

```
FileOpenFlags flags = FileOpenFlags_Create | FileOpenFlags_Truncate;
```

will probably work in C, but fail miserably in C++ ;)